# How to find the domain of definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The letter $z$ represents the function which depends on two independent variables which are represented by $x$ and $y$ in this equation.

I want to ask how to find the domain of definition of this function and I want to know the full answer with the steps explained.

$$z=\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$$

Comment: We want you to show some effort.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: LaTex is 3GB; it is very big I can't download it. I'm sorry.

Comment: @coding_beginner You can learn it. It's not so hard. ;)

Comment: Technically, it's not LaTeX, it's MathJax. And no download necessary. This site takes care of that part for you. You just need to tell it to do so. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a brief guide on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we are working with real variables $z$ is defined iff $4-x^{2}-y^{2} \geq 0$ iff $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 4$. So the domain is   $\{(x,y): x^{2}+y^{2} \leq 4\}$.  Geometrically this represents the points inside and on the circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin.

Comment: so can the domain be written like this?

domf={all x,y which belongs is a set of real numbers then for (x,y) such that x^2 + y^4 <= 4}

Comment: Yes, what I have written is a complete answer.

Comment: I understand every part of your answer except the "Geometrically..." part. Can you explain to me why geometrically it doesn't represent the points outside and on the circle of radius. And what is the meaning of "2 centered at the origin"?.

Comment: Points outside the circle are given by $x^{2}+y^{2} >4$. Note that $\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}$ is distance of the point $(x,y)$ from $(0,0)$.

Comment: the answer you gave me is correct but I can't upvote it because I have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: @coding_beginner you can accept the answer.